# Cookies Expires is not working as per expectation

Tags: c#, cookies, razor, razor-pages

I keep getting an error while using this line of code, I'm trying to let the cookie "myCookie" to expire when it's 12:00 am.

But I'm not sure why I'm unable to do this.

These are the errors:

If I use this,

```
Response.Cookies["myCookie"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
```

I got this:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IResponseCookies'

If I use this,

```
Response.Cookies("myCookie").Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
```

I got this:

> Non-invocable member 'HttpResponse.Cookies' cannot be used like a method.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Cookie Options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.expires?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_CookieOptions_Expires):

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
};
Response.Cookies.Append("myCookie", "value1", cookieOptions);
```

> Cookie options provide access to additional configuration of cookies.

Read more here https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/cookies